# Tab index on floating inputs

Tags: html, css, tabindex

I have a page with a for layout where one half of the page is dynamic width an the other is fixed. This is achieved by floating the fixed width side to the right. It all displays fine but because the fixed width markup comes before the dynamic width markup the tab ordering gets thrown off.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BaMqG/

How can i overcome this without resorting to putting tabindex properties on the inputs?

Comment: 1. Do you want to navigate your inputs by row or by "block"? 2. Can you float left the fixed group? 3. What's wrong with tabindex property?

Comment: 1.I want to navigate accross the row left to right. 2.The fixed group has to come after the dynamic group. 3.The form can increase in size (more inputs) via javascript and so keeping track on teh tab index would become a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the same looking form with no tab index to work by using tables.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ymSGM/

I would still be interested if it can be done any other way.

Comment: Honestly, mixing fixed and percent widths in your layout is inherently problematic in html/css. You either need to write a script to handle the dynamic nature of your form, or avoid the issue altogether by using tables. There are pros and cons to each. If semantic markup is less important in this scenario than avoiding excess javascript, then tables are probably the best bet you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to dynamically set the tabindexes with a loop and counter variable. Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/BaMqG/22/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('.wrapper').each(function(){
        $(this).children('.dynamic').children('input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("tabindex",i); 
            i++;
        });
        $(this).children('.fixed').children('input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("tabindex",i);
            i++;
        });
    });
});​
```

The initial value for i can be set to whatever tabindex number you want to start from.

Comment: Yes I thought of this, but this part of the form sits in the middle of the full form and so when I add a new form line via js not only would its tab index need updating so would all of the form that follows it. This is why I would like a non tab index solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a practical non-tabindex solution to this, but I could easily modify this js to accomplish what you want. Really, its going to take js no matter what, and this is probably the least code-heavy way to do it.

Comment: However, if you post a link to your page, I can look at alternate solutions.

Comment: I know it can be done but I was really after a html/css fix really rather that tabindex/javascript solution. I dont have a link im afraid but the fiddle page basically covers it.